# Prove uncountability of R using an algorithm?

Tags: logic, computer-science, infinity, turing-machines

Let's say I want to prove uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$ using an algorithm (I will use Python).

I will consider reals $0 \le x \lt 1$ and represent the decimal development of $x$ with a generator.

If I have a generator of reals, I can produce a new real (that is, a generator) based on an iterable of reals using diagonal argument :

```
def diag_argument(reals):
 n = 0
 for x in reals:
   for i, d in enumerate(x):
    if i == n:
     yield (d+1) % 10
     break
   n += 1
```

If I could write an `enumerate_R` function, `diag_argument(enumerate_R())` would produce a new real.

I would be tempted to say that this proves that $\mathbb{R}$ is not recursively enumerable. Is that correct ? (I don't know much about logic / CS)

If I want to use my `diag_argument` function to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable, can I suppose there is some kind of "oracle" function `enumerate_R` and still use my `diag_argument` function to show a contradiction ?

Would that be an acceptable proof from a logical point of view, in the context of set theory ?

Comment: The diagonal argument is an abstract method assuming we have infinite many entries and can construct an infinite diagonal. This cannot be done with a computer, since a computer (or even a turing machine) is always limited to finite calculations. Oracles are also very hypothetical machines that can do some specific job perfectly and without needing considerable time. In short , computers cannot deal with Cantor-like constructions and proofs.

Comment: This is really not a proof "by an algorithm". You have to _show_ that diag_argument(reals)$ returns a "new" real, and having shown that you don't use Python anywhere.

Comment: OK so we cannot even prove that R isn't recursively enumerable this way, because we cannot "return a real" (computers can only return integers in the end). Right ?

That still bothers me though, because we can return a procedure/generator which will enumerate all the decimals of a "new" real...

Comment: I wonder if that intuition doesn't correspond to Infinite Time Turing Machines (see https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-74593-8_5).

Comment: This indeed shows that there is no effective (i.e. computable) enumeration of all computable real numbers.

Comment: And indeed, using oracles, this gives you that the reals are uncountable. The point is that for any countably many reals, there is a real $s$ that "sees" all of them (technically, they are Turing reducible to $s$), and any real only "sees" countably many other reals (technically, given any real $r$, only countably many reals are Turing reducible to $r$), so if we use $s$ as an oracle to list the reals and run the diagonal argument algorithm, we indeed end up with a real not in the list (i.e., not Turing reducible to $s$).